# Is video editing off-topic?

Tags: discussion

The FAQ currently says this website is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games. However, Blender is a full-featured and very competent video editor. Especially since the release of Tears of Steel, the software is a state-of-the-art special effects tool for live action film. Should questions related to non-animation video and compositing be allowed, since this is a very large (although lesser-known) feature of Blender?

Comment: This was asked eight years ago and the help center page https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic still suggests that only questions about modeling and animation are on-topic. This should probably be fixed, as the non-modeling uses of blender are now well established.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not, the site *is* about Blender, if topics such as the compositor, tracker and the game engine are on topic, so is the vse. *However,* the question must relate to a problem within Blender or with Blender's VSE and not about just video editing or video editing techniques etc.

Answer (score 3):

## NO

The FAQ is still WIP, so don't let that define your view of what the site is for. If you have good Video Editing questions or knowledge, feel free to add them/it.

(The yes I had originally was answering the question in the body of your question).